# DeleteOnSubmit() and SubmitChanges() don't work. No exception or error. InsertOnSubmit() works fine

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I got this code to Delete a Category row from a Database. The Category has only 2 columns: Id and Name.
It doesn't announce any errors. It just doesn't work.

If it worked, it should Redirect to `Categories/Index`. Instead, it shows `Categories/Delete` but now without any Category as parameter.

```
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var category = db.Categories.Where(r => r.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
            return View(category); 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(Category category)
        {
            try
            {
                Category c = db.Categories
                    .Where(r => r.Id == category.Id)
                    .Single<Category>();
                db.Categories.DeleteOnSubmit(c);
                db.SubmitChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(category);
            }
        }
```

But this code for the Create action works just fine:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Category c = new Category();
        return View(c);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Category category)
    {
        try
        {
            Category x = new Category
            {
                Name = category.Name
            };
            db.Categories.InsertOnSubmit(x);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think it is throwing an error, you wouldn't know because it is being swallowed and you are returning the default (Index) View. Catch the exception and see what it is.

Comment: Nope. There's none. I've spent over an hour looking at this. There's no error. I just doesnt work.

Comment: So you changed your code? As is you would never know an exception was thrown unless you were debugging and had the Exception Settings configured to break on all Common Language Runtime Exceptions.

Comment: No idea what you mean by breaking on CLR. I'm new to Visual (still a first-year student). I just look at all the error/message/warning tabs and there's nothing. I also looked at the event tab in the debugging windows: nothing.

Comment: instead of just `catch`, do `catch(Exception ex) { return View(); }`. Put a breakpoint (F9) on "return View()" and if the breakpoint is hit you can look at the properties of `ex`. You can also press ctrl+D, E and check the box next to "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in the Exception Settings window that will open.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger

Comment: Turns out the particular Row I was testing the Delete functionality on was referenced as Foreign Key from another table. So that's why it couldn't be deleted.
I tested deleting a row that was not referenced as foreign key by any table. Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the row I wanted to test the Delete functionality on was referenced as a foreign key by another table in the database.

I tested deleting a row that was not referenced by any other table. Works just fine.

Comment: ...and you would have figured that out long ago if you were doing exception handling :)